# XSLT, using the + character in a variable value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Is it possible to create a variable in xslt and assign it the value "10+"  ?

Assigning "10" is fine, but when I add the + sign I get an "Unexpected token '<eof>' in the expression..." exception.

Comment: Show us what you have so far. You must be quoting wrongly but it's hard to see where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Max Toro said, use quotes for strings. This includes quotes inside of the "" quotes of an attribute value (such as `select=""`).

Example:

```
<xsl:variable name="var" select="'10+'"/>
```

You can also do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="var">10+</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: `<xsl:variable name="var">10+</xsl:variable>` is not recommended since you are creating a text node, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes for strings, else the processor will think it's an expression:

```
'10+'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a variable in
>   xslt and assign it the value "10+" ?

**Yes. This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="vStr" select="'10+'"/>

     "<xsl:value-of select="$vStr"/>"
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document** (not used), produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
 "10+"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may not be quoting enough. Your code should look something like:

```
<xsl:variable name='my-var' select="'10+'"/>
```